# Confused about visa question: "Voluntarily elected to depart the UK" ? Yes or No?

Tags: visas, uk, study, applications

I applied and successfully received a student visa from India in October 2017. I traveled to the UK on October 12, but could not register for the course. Since the latest registration date for my course, October 13, was already over, I left the UK willingly on the 16th. I did not collect my BRP from the university. Afterwards, I withdrew from the course and got the course withdrawal letter from UCAS and a full refund from the university for the tuition fees.

I have only received an email on March 23, 2018 from Home Office, which mentions that my previous Tier 4 visa has been curtailed, citing non-commencement of my studies with my university.

Now, I am applying for May 2018 intake for the same course at another university. I have already paid the full tuition fees and also received the CAS letter.

Since now I am submitting a fresh Tier 4 visa application, kindly guide me for replies to the following 2 questions mentioned in the application:

1. Have you ever been deported, removed or otherwise required to leave the 
   UK? Yes/No
2. Have you ever voluntary elected to depart the UK? Yes/No. (If yes, what do I answer "under immigration decision and the papers you were served", and "reference number" as the reference number on email is given in form of XXXXXX1234).

Comment: This is about a question on a visa application, and nothing to do with immigration.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid <1 year fits year, >1 year fits at Expatriates.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with years or migration. If you read it, its asking how to answer a specific question on a visa application - which everyone has to do irrespective of the visa type or travel type.

Answer (score 23):

1. No
2. No

The second part is for when:

1. You have overstayed and left on your own accord (ie, were not deported) and/or
2. At the immigration check point - you were inadmissible and have voluntarily decided to revoke your application for admission.

In either of the cases above, you are given specific papers from immigration that you use as proof of your exit circumstances.

Either of those cases do not apply to you because you were lawfully admitted to the UK, however you were unable to stay for the purpose of admission (study) so you left on your own accord.

You should keep that email and reference number since you need to explain why you departed and what was the reason your visa was terminated.

Comment: Is it fair to say the phrasing of question 2 is awful. Isn't every tourist voluntarily departing when they end their vacation?

Comment: @Goose the phrasing of everything written by the UK Border Agency / UK Visas and Immigration / The UK Home Office is always awful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Shall I include a letter along with my application addressed to UKVI detailing my previous student visa curtailment, if i select "No" to above question, as I don't want to be seen hiding any facts on purpose?